# Keep hover state active across divs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to know how you keep the hover state of div element active accross multiple div elements.
So if i hover over Menu-item 1 then go to Menu-item 6 Menu item 1 is active while menu item 6 is active then I'd goto menu item 9 and thats active so my previous Menu Items are active.

CSS:

```
.menuitem-active {
     background-color: #ff9900;
}
.menuitem {
     background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 1</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 2</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 3</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 4</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 5</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 6</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 7</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 8</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div class="menu">
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 9</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 10</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 11</div>
        <div class="menu-item">Menu Item 12</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('.container .menu .menu-item').mouseenter(function(){

});
```

Comment: @litteman , in that case you should just implement mouseenter , don't do anything on mouseleave.

Comment: then all menu items would have a active hover state that doesn't make sense

Comment: Could you clarify your question a little? I don't follow what you want to happen when you mouseover something, and then mouseout. Do you only want *one* element at a time to be considered 'active'? If so, you might find it easier to simply use unordered lists and CSS, rather than JavaScript.

Comment: You can do this in pure CSS(3): http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/W8McN/ (I added only webkit vendor prefixes, because that's the only browser that matters =p) Alright I added `-moz-` too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you define a `selected` class for the hover effect:

```
$('.container .menu .menu-item').mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

The `siblings()` function will select the menu items only within the current element's parent.

Comment: I don't think that would do what I awant I would have a mouseleave event aswell to perform the un active state

Comment: You don't need a mouseleave, as if you hover over a menu item in the same group, it will automatically deactivate all the others in the same group as well as selecting the current one. If you do mouseleave, nothing would stay active as soon as your mouse leaves, which is what I thought you don't want to do.

Comment: @littleman , can you describle what do you mean by active state , you want to show in a different color or so ?

Comment: @littleMan Have a look at it in action, is this not what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/pRCJA/1/

Comment: Ok my menu items will have children div elements that do have a state for selected, div elements for the corners for left and right side of my menu item Im just a bit confused as to remove the selected and unselected states in your code I haven't tried this out yet. I have a mouseleave event to romve the classes for selected

Comment: Have a look at this jsfiddle demo, you can use the same code as above, just do some additional DOM tree traversing to go deeper in the tree before `removeClass()` and `addClass()`: http://jsfiddle.net/pRCJA/2/

Answer (score 1):

you might want to close off some of those class container since it was left unclosed.
Anyhow, mouseenter doesn't really seem practical since the divs will span 100% and as you move down, every one of them will become active.

Assuming you set an active style in css just change its attribute to "active" or "item"
I'd recommend changing it to click event

```
$('.container .menu .menu-item').click(function() {
    $(this).attr("class","menu-active");
});
```

Here is an example http://jsfiddle.net/robx/RsNw3/

Comment: for these type of menus , it better to use UL or OL...lists

Comment: if you insist on mouseenter, it seems to me you will need to shrink the div width, and or have it all active as the user moves down the list hovering over all div elements.

Comment: Yah, but he didn't put in that in, so I am only giving him what he asked for using his code ;)

Comment: There we go. Updated the jsFiddle to using his code and using UL list to show. Similar, but yes menu's are almost always preferred using UL or OL since that is what they were meant for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure CSS(3): http://jsfiddle.net/rudiedirkx/W8McN

I added `-webkit-` and `-moz-` vendor prefixes, because (unstandardized) transitions are necessary for this.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
$('.container > .menu > .menu-item').hover(

function() { // first function, the 'mouseenter'
    $(this).addClass('active');
},
function() { // the second function, the 'mouseleave'
    $(this).removeClass('active')
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/FcZXb/1/).

Incidentally, please pay attention to your quoting of attribute values, the `class="container` left an un-termintated string, which can cause problems all by itself.